# Rails link_to for a create action trying to call search action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a link in my Rails app that is supposed to add a user to a trip. The link itself is this:

```
<%= link_to "Add to trip", {:url => trip_users_url(@trip.id, {:user_id => user.id}), :remote => true, :method => :post}, :class => 'button absolute' %>
```

And the new and create method in the trip_users_controller is as follows:

```
def new
    body_attributes 'add-crew', 'main-feed'

    if params[:trips_user] && !params[:trips_user][:email].blank?
      authorize! :create, @trip.trips_users.new
      @trips_users = @trip.trips_users.find(:first, :include => :user, :conditions => {"users.email" => params[:trips_user][:email]})
      if @trips_users.blank?
        name = params[:trips_user][:email]
        if !User.name_like(name).blank?
          @users = User.name_like(name)
        else
          @users = User.email_like(name)
        end
        @trips_users = []
        @users.each do |user|
          @trips_users << @trip.trips_users.new(:user => user)
        end
        @invitation = @trip.invitations.find_by_email(params[:trips_user][:email])
        @invitation ||= @trip.invitations.new(:email => params[:trips_user][:email]) if params[:trips_user][:email].match(/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i)
      end
    end
  end

def create
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    authorize! :create, TripsUser.new(:user => @user, :trip => @trip)
    unless @trip.users.include? @user
      @trip.users << @user
      add_news(:added_user, @trip, {:user_id => @user.id})
      flash[:notice] = "#{@user.name} was added to the trip."
    end
  end
```

However when I click on the link, it seems to be trying to call the search action for some reason and gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError in TripsUsersController#search

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

The parameters it passes are:

```
{"method"=>"post",
 "remote"=>"true",
 "url"=>"http://localhost:3000/trips/18/users?user_id=11",
 "trip_id"=>"18-Testing"}
```

So it clearly knows the trip, and the user_id required...

Any ideas?

** EDIT **

Here is the relevant section of the routes:

```
map.resources :trips, :member => {:share => :get, :map => :get, :favourite => [:post, :get]}, :collection => {:find_boat => :get} do |trips|
    trips.resources :photos
    trips.resources :videos
    trips.resources :users, :controller => "trips_users", :collection => {:search => [:get, :post]}
    trips.resources :paths
    trips.resources :posts
    trips.resources :invitations
  end
```

Comment: can you provide related lines in your routes file?

Comment: Try  `<%= link_to("Add to trip", trip_users_url(@trip.id, {:user_id => user.id}), remote: true, method: :post, class: 'button absolute') %>`. I'm not sure this will fix the issue but using a hash for the second param is usually only done when using `{ controller: 'Foo', action: 'bar' }`

Comment: Right, as papirtiger said, ruby will see that hash as extra parameters for the url, which is why you see the `method`, `remote`, and `url` as parameters.

Comment: I've tried that and it removed the error, but still didn't actually add the user to the trip, all it did was redirect the page back one....

Comment: What URL does the `link_to` point to now? In addition in your server console, what are the first 2 lines for each request that occurs when you click the link ex. `Started GET "/" for ...` `Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML`?

Comment: Processing by TripsUsersController#search as HTML
INFO      Parameters: {"method"=>"post", "remote"=>"true", "url"=>"http://localhost:3000/trips/18/users?user_id=11", "trip_id"=>"18-Testing"}

Comment: and in the parameters it still points to this url: url"=>"http://localhost:3000/trips/18/users?user_id=11

Comment: Looks like it still isn't picking the URL up properly. when you make a `<%= link_to %>` and don't supply a string as the 2nd argument, it will link to the page it is currently on. The format should be `<%= "Link Text", <x>_path({parameters}), {HTML attributes} %>` In your case because the second argument is a hash, `{:url => trip_users_url(@trip.id, {:user_id => user.id}), :remote => true, :method => :post}` they are being interpreted as parameters for the current page.

Comment: I've tried loads of different variations of the link_to but none of it seems to be making any difference...

Comment: If your current one looks like `<%= link_to("Add to trip", trip_users_url(@trip.id, {:user_id => user.id}), remote: true, method: :post, class: 'button absolute') %>` as papirtiger said, the only thing I can think of is your page isn't being updated as you're making these changes. What happens if you change it to `<%= link_to "Test", trip_users_url(18) %>`?

Comment: Ok, so using the code you suggested (I must have missed something last time), it now send a different response (still not the correct one but I feel like it's getting closer! :D) Started GET "/trips/18/users?user_id=11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-21 18:26:09 +0100
INFO      Processing by TripsUsersController#index as HTML
INFO      Parameters: {"user_id"=>"11", "trip_id"=>"18"}